# Trigger to allow 1 car per customer and not let another customer rent an already rented vehicle between rental and return date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a project based on Databases (Oracle) to create a Rental shop for cars. So far it's been going well but I got stuck on a trigger that has to check the customer as well as the car between the rental as well as the return date, so that a customer who's already rented a vehicle cannot rent another and another customer cannot rent an already rented vehicle.

Rental Table:

```
CREATE TABLE RentAuto
(
auto_id INT,
customer_id INT,
employee_id INT,
date_rent DATE,
date_return DATE,
rent_days VARCHAR2(5)
);
```

Automobile Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Automobile 
(
auto_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
year_of_production VARCHAR(10),
auto_current_km VARCHAR(20),
price_per_day VARCHAR(20),
color_id INT,
is_auto_av INT,
model_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY(auto_id)
);
```

Insert into the Table:

```
INSERT INTO RentAuto (auto_id,customer_id,employee_id,date_rent,date_return, rent_days)
VALUES(14,13,3,TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), '29-03-2022','2');
```

The trigger I wrote below gives me an error on the IF statement and I can't figure out how to fix it.
(**PLS-00201:identifier 'NEW.CUSTOMER_ID' must be declared**)

```
create or replace TRIGGER RENTINGTRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF AUTO_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,DATE_RENT,DATE_RETURN ON RENTAUTO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF RENTAUTO.CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID
and ((new.DATE_RENT >= RentAuto.DATE_RETURN and new.DATE_RENT < RentAuto.DATE_RETURN)
        or (new.DATE_RETURN > RentAuto.DATE_RENT and new.DATE_RETURN < RentAuto.DATE_RETURN))
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2099, 'You can only book one car per single customer a day');
IF RentAuto.AUTO_ID = :NEW.AUTO_ID
and 
 ((new.date_rent >= RentAuto.date_return and new.date_rent < RentAuto.date_return)
    or (new.date_return > RentAuto.date_rent and new.date_return < RentAuto.date_return))
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2099, 'Car has already been rented by another customer!');
END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you using a trigger to implement this instead of a check constraint? It also might be possible to implement using only a unique constraint.

Comment: @Dai I know it's bad practice to implement it as a trigger but I'm required do it with a trigger (that's how the person who handed us the project said so)

Comment: At some places you are missing the colon before `new`. And in `IF RENTAUTO.CUSTOMER_ID`, which row is `RENTAUTO` supposed to be? There is a :new row and an :old row in a trigger, that's it.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Well It's basically trying to compare the customer who's id is in RentAuto (the table) and the one the newly inserted one. I'm just unsure how to do it.

Comment: What you need here is queries to look for overlapping rows in the table. The problem with this: The table you want to query is in the process of changing. The easiest way to solve this would be an after statement trigger. If you want it more sophisticated you need a compound trigger.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah I've never had to implement a compound trigger before but I'll check it out, thanks a lot!

Comment: You have several columns that are defined as VARCHAR. In oracle they should be VARCHAR2.  Also you have several columns that are obviously numeric data, but you have defined as VARCHAR - year_of_production, auto_current_km, price_per_day, rent_days. Conversly, you have some columns that are defined as INT, but the nature of the data is not numeric - even if, by standard, valid data contains only numeric CHARACTERS -  customer_id, employee_id.  Rule of thumb - if you wouldn't do math on it,  it ain't a number. No need for rent_days, as that can always be computed from date_return - date_rent.

Comment: @EdStevens I changed everything as you mentioned, thank you a lot! It's fully working now with the new column values, I also put a check constraint on RentAuto so the return date cannot be lower than the rent date:

ALTER TABLE RentAuto
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_PERIOD CHECK (date_rent IS NULL OR date_return > date_rent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple after statement trigger, that throws an exception when an insert or update leads to a customer booking more than one car a day or a car getting booked more than once a day.

If the insert or update statement is on more than one row, the trigger doesn't tell us which booking led to failure. Also, each time an insert or update occurs we must scan the whole table for clashes. If you only want to react on the row(s) being inserted or updated, you need a compound trigger, where you remember the rows in question in the "after each row" part and then compare them to the other rows in the table in the "after statement" part.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER rentingtrigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF auto_id, customer_id, date_rent, date_return ON rentauto
  v_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  select count(*)
  into v_count
  from rentauto
  where exists
  (
    select null
    from rentauto other
    where other.customer_id = rentauto.customer_id
    and other.date_rent <= rentauto.date_return
    and other.date_return >= rentauto.date_rent
    and other.rowid <> rentauto.rowid
  );

  IF v_count > 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20099, 'You can only book one car per single customer a day');
  END IF;

  select count(*)
  into v_count
  from rentauto
  where exists
  (
    select null
    from rentauto other
    where other.auto_id = rentauto.auto_id
    and other.date_rent <= rentauto.date_return
    and other.date_return >= rentauto.date_rent
    and other.rowid <> rentauto.rowid
  );

  IF v_count > 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20099, 'Car has already been rented by another customer!');
  END IF;
END rentingtrigger;
```